# Vim plugin to Web Development with Catalyst (Perl)

Tags: perl, vim, catalyst

I always used vim to work in Perl Projects. Now I am starting working in webdev with Catalyst (Perl MVC).
It seems like code assist with CSS, HTML and javascript in Vim is not updated to CSS3 and HTML5.
What are the best plugins specifically to work with web development in Catalyst (Perl)?

Comment: um... do you want stuff to work with Perl? or with TT? or css and html 5? just by reading this I don't see what this has to do with catalyst at all..

Comment: Actually with all that together. Do you do web dev with Catalyst? Do you use vim? What are the plugins that help you out in your work?

Comment: occasionally ... I've also been a contributor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [TT2 Syntax Highlighting Plugin](https://github.com/petdance/vim-perl) which is apparently now part of an Andy Lester repo... I worked on adding HTML 5 tags to [the html5 syntax highlighting plugin](https://github.com/xenoterracide/html.vim), appears I did the same with [css](https://github.com/xenoterracide/css.vim). I also worked on the more modern [Perl](https://github.com/rkitover/perl-vim-mxd) syntax highlighting stuff, which has merged Andy Lester's repo, but has the modern perl highlighting, so I would install that.